# Solr index-time field boost

Tags: solr

Is there a way to store a field with a string of individually boosted keywords? Example: storing... 'Science'^2.0, 'Vehicles'^8.0, 'Crimes'^11.0 in a single field?

Answer (score 3):

Index-time boosts are indeed only [applied per field](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22), and you cannot boost terms via [copyfield](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) (copy a bunch of boosted fields into an unboosted field and have the boost apply per copy).

However, you can [use this hack](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/200703.mbox/%3Cc68e39170703021501m7c7c006fw629a4434f9fc8f28@mail.gmail.com%3E) to create your own "boost" by copying a term multiple times into the same field. It will "boost" the relevancy of the term if you use the copied field instead of the original for search queries. It will not, however, be an "exact" boost.

Answer (score 2):

No. Index-time boosts are applied [per-doc](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_on_.22doc.22) and/or [per-field](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22).

You may of course use keyword boosting at query-time.

Another option (depending on what you need concretely) would be using [Payloads](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Payloads)

Comment: Could I use a dynamic field? So, store a boost in the value and have fields like, science_taxonomy and crimes_taxonomy and have the dynamic field of *_taxonomy ???